# Inflate Layout NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I want to inflate a layout when the player is death (a game over layout).
I tried it like this:

```
View GameOverDialog;

LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
GameOverDialog = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.lose, null, false);
rlGame.addView(GameOverDialog);
GameOverDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And when the player dies:

```
private void lose(){
    GameOverDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I also use a Handler so I can send a message when the player dies:

```
final static int DEATH = 0, LOSE = 1;

final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == DEATH) {
            //play music
            postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.what = LOSE;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        if (msg.what == LOSE) {
            lose();
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

But when the Handler calls the lose() method, the application crashes and I get a NullPointerException.
I hope someone can help me :).

Thanks in advance!
Joeri.

**EDIT**

Full class:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

final static int DEATH = 0, LOSE = 1;
RelativeLayout rlGame;
GamePanel game_panel;
private int ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight;
View GameOverDialog;
ImageView retry, quit;
TextView textRetry, textQuit;

final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == DEATH) {
            //play music
            postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.what = LOSE;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        if (msg.what == LOSE) {
            lose();
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    rlGame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlGame);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    final int height = dm.heightPixels;
    final int width = dm.widthPixels;

    game_panel = new GamePanel(getApplicationContext(), width, height, rlGame);
    rlGame.addView(game_panel);

    LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    GameOverDialog = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.lose, null, false);
    rlGame.addView(GameOverDialog);
    retry = (ImageView) GameOverDialog.findViewById(R.id.retry);
    retry.setOnTouchListener(new TouchButton(retry, textRetry));
    quit = (ImageView) GameOverDialog.findViewById(R.id.quit);
    quit.setOnTouchListener(new TouchButton(quit, textQuit));
    textRetry = (TextView)GameOverDialog.findViewById(R.id.textRetry);
    textQuit = (TextView)GameOverDialog.findViewById(R.id.textQuit);
    GameOverDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

private void lose() {
    GameOverDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

}

I also tried to set visibility to VISIBLE in the onBackPressed method, this worked, I don't know why, but in the handler goes something wrong I think...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: is `GameOverDialog` stored in the class variables? Please show the full class

Comment: try calling lose() inside postDelayed()

Comment: I tried to call lose() inside postDelayed, but that didn't work

Comment: Post the full error message and mark the line where it occurs.

Comment: I surrounded the GameOverDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); with an if statement: if(GameOverDialog != null)
   GameOverDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  else
   Log.d("GameOverDialog", "= NULL");      and I saw that GameOverDialog = null

Comment: Full error: 03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347): Process: com.jakkerman.appgame, PID: 22347
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347):  at com.jakkerman.appgame.Game.lose(Game.java:104)
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347):  at com.jakkerman.appgame.Game.access$0(Game.java:102)
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347):  at com.jakkerman.appgame.Game$1.handleMessage(Game.java:45)

Comment: and more, but I don't think it is necessary: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 20:38:15.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22347):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Comment: Necessary stuff: **03-08 20:49:07.366: E/AndroidRuntime(22641): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 20:49:07.366: E/AndroidRuntime(22641):  at com.jakkerman.appgame.Game.lose(Game.java:104)
03-08 20:49:07.366: E/AndroidRuntime(22641):  at com.jakkerman.appgame.Game.access$0(Game.java:102)
03-08 20:49:07.366: E/AndroidRuntime(22641):  at com.jakkerman.appgame.Game$1.handleMessage(Game.java:45)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `getApplicationContext()` when you don't have to:

```
game_panel = new GamePanel(this, width, height, rlGame);
rlGame.addView(game_panel);

LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater)
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

**Edit:**

As per your comment (next time, please just update your question), it seems that the handleMessage is called before `onCreate` where your variable is set. So set your listener after the field is initialized:

```
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Init field
    GameOverDialog = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.lose, null, false);
    // Set the handler
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == DEATH) {
                //play music
                postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                        msg.what = LOSE;
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
            if (msg.what == LOSE) {
                lose();
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: I dont get the error anymore but now I get another error at the location where I set a message for the handler (when the player dies): Message msg = gamepanel.game.handler.obtainMessage (); msg.what = 0; gamepanel.game.handler.sendMessage (msg);      It is btw a nullpointerexception again

Comment: @Joeri you're calling the handler too early -- activity `Game` is not yet ready. Seems like a whole new problem here so might as well ask another question.

Comment: But Game is the first activity then I call the GamePanel and in the GamePanel I call the Player and there (in the Player class) I have the code above with the message. In the Game activity I initialized the handler before the GamePanel class so it should be ready...

Comment: should I ask a new question?